# How to store sensitive files and only allow access to certain users

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, directory

I have a web app that lets users store files which contain sensitive information.
So far I've written code so that if they which to view their files, they go through **view.php?id=xx** and a check is done through a database to confirm that they are allowed to look at said file. As an example, John uploads **"information.pdf"** to the folder **"uploads"** which is found at **"www.mysite.com/uploads"**, so the file's exact path would be **"http://www.mysite.com/uploads/information.pdf"**, and in the database this same file has an id of , say, 2, so he would get to it via **view.php?id=2**.

**Question**

How do I stop anyone from just going to the exact path and looking at his sensitive file?

**What I've done**

Written the code to only allow access to files if users go through my website, not directly.

I have looked at the recommended questions for the same title, however have had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put it in a publicly accessible path like `http://www.mysite.com/uploads/`. Put it outside htdocs and only allow access through your `view.php`

If you want to give download facility to the owner just create a`download.php` that checks permission same way as `view.php` but instead of viewing it lets the user to download.

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks! Would I need to give that folder the 777 permission?

Comment: Also, how is it that I access the file through `view.php` if it is outside of the public directory? Previously I would have gone straight for it through `http://www.mysite.com/uploads/file.pdf` ? Do I instead tell it to find the file at `/home/upload_directory` which is outside the `/home/public_html/` directory?

Comment: `/home/upload_dir` is fine. In `view.php` you access by file path NOT http URL for sure. And use permission 777 if needed. Try loew ones first.